AuthMethod name for using access token(connetion string) as authentication method in azure redis cache
what should be the "preferred-data-persistence-auth-method" while using connection string(access token) as a auth method
I am changing the authentication method of a redis resource from managedidentity to connection string what should be added in redis config PreferredDataPersistenceAuthMethod. Currently it is "preferred-data-persistence-auth-method": "ManagedIdentity"


            WriteLine("Connecting with an access key...");
            connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString!, AzureCacheForRedis.ConfigureForAzure, connectionLog);```

Here's the full code implementing the connection to an Azure Cache for Redis resource using a connection string  as the authentication method
package used StackExchange.Redis and code reference from git.

 ConnectionMultiplexer? connectionMultiplexer = null;
 StringWriter connectionLog = new();

 try
 {
    
     Console.Write("Enter Redis cache connection string: ");
     var connectionString = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();

     
     Console.WriteLine("Connecting with a connection string...");
     connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString!, null, connectionLog);

     // Check if connection was successful
     if (connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully!");
         Console.WriteLine();
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to Redis cache.");
         return;
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"Failed to connect: {ex}");
     Console.WriteLine();
     return;
 }
 finally
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Connection log from StackExchange.Redis:");
     Console.WriteLine(connectionLog);
 }

  
 var database = connectionMultiplexer?.GetDatabase();
 while (true)
 {
   
     try
     {
         
         var value = database!.StringGet("key");
         database.StringSet("key", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
         Console.Write("+");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       
         Console.Error.WriteLine($"Failed to execute a Redis command: {ex}");
     }

     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
 }


Output:

